# Circular Lighting Artifacts

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

How to avoid the circular patterns on a plain diffuse surface while projecting light?
[image: Rendered output]

I am trying to project a few patterns on objects in Cycles render. When I project a plain white light on a diffuse surface (a plane), I could see concentric rings on close observation. Could someone help on how to avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is kinda normal is most lighting shading though...

Comment: Try to render in 16-bit image, 8-bit is quite less for image to store data. It might still stay in strip afterward in a 8-bit monitor setup. But it help you to save more color information in your file.